# Receiving Broken Links from my Chrome Extension when I Embed Links

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In the chrome extension I'm developing, I'm using `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML` to return results from my .js file to my HTML, but my embedded links aren't working correctly. Instead of being hyperlinked with, for example, stackoverflow.com, I'm getting links like the following: `chrome-extension://ijmlokbcldclhokfgkfilhopdehmkhjh/stackoverflow.com`

I couldn't find anything to help on stackoverflow, so below is my code:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: `
  var sent_text = document.domain;
  information = sent_text;
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: sent_text}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);})
  `});
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  return_value = request.greeting.split(",")[2]; // For now, only need domain.
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
  "<a href='" + return_value + "'>" + return_value + "</a>";
  sendResponse({farewell: request.greeting});
  });
```

To rephrase, I'm having weird, broken links that begin with "extension://".

Comment: Sounds like your return_value doesn't start with `https://`

Comment: Thanks! Silly mistake.